# Why did the row count of my Dataframe increase after using the .drop method?

Tags: python, pandas, drop

I was trying to drop play count that is greater than 5? I noticed when I use the line of code below, the shape of my data increase from 130398 rows × 7 columns to 400730 rows × 7 columns, does any one know why?

```
df_final=df.drop(df[df.play_count> 5].index)
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. Are you using Pandas? If you are, please add the tag for it. Next, it'd help to provide a [mre] including a sample of your data. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341) for specifics. For more tips, see [ask]. You can [edit].

Comment: Oh, and [please don't post pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). Instead, copy the text itself and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](/editing-help#code).

Answer (score 1):

`drop()` function in Pandas doesn't add new rows, it does the opposite as your understanding. (Documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html)

From my speculation, the number `130398` is from `df_final` from the previous cell. While `df_final=df.drop(df[df.play_count> 5].index)`, you use the original `df` instead of `df_final` that you observed the number of rows.

Try running the `df_final` again and making sure that it has the right number of rows, then probably try using:

```
df_final = df_final.drop(df_final[df_final.play_count> 5].index)
```